# Словить инициатора анимации на элементе по названию анимируемого свойства

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, отладка

Есть 3 блока в одном диве. Все имеют инлайново прописанные свойства left: -100500px; Предполагаю они выставляются при загруке страницы. После клика происходит очень много событий дом-манипуляций, ajax-запросов в целом в папке js возле 15 скриптов. Я слышал о blackbox в devtool. Но вчера это не помогло мне. Subtree-modifications не останавливают выполнение скриптов. Можно ли написать функцию которая будет к примеру выводить в консоль название другой функции, которая обрабатывает свойство left?

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_45344/index.html

Если все-таки в chrome devtool debugger или firebug есть способ узнать нужную мне информацию, то это тоже будет интересно.
[image: Не помогает]

Что анимирует фигуры под текстом? [image: фигуры?]

Comment: можно сайт или код куда-то выкинуть, тут же не шоу экстрасеков

Comment: _Subtree-modifications не останавливают выполнение скриптов_ - в хроме вроде можно на это оставить breakpoint

Comment: @Grundy Как постаить breakpoint на модификацию елемента либо свойства?

Comment: @FrankSinatra ну если вам проще найти и показать как найти, а не просто ткнуть мне нужній мануал, то пожалуйста прочитайте обновленный вопрос.

Comment: consol.log(); в функция лепите и смотрите какие отрабатывают, а какие нет, все на js написано, анимирует джс после клика и потом уже загрузки экрана срабатывает функция, исходных файлов нет, ищите по классам что вам нужно, вопрос не раскрыт полностью то, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: @FrankSinatra, я ищу кусок кода который после удовлетворения ajax-запроса меняет значение свойства left для блоков с классами partLeft, partRight и partMenu. Все исходные коды с которыми я работаю находятся там во вкладке sources.

Хочу познавать и делать подобные вещи. Но куда более важно узнать как более опытніе программисты дебажат и рефакторят чужой код. Не разобравшись в том как оно устроено, нельзя усовершенствовать его. Теперь вопрос раскрыт полностью?

Comment: [Set a breakpoint on DOM change](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints#dom)

Comment: @Grundy я делал именно это (скрин в описании), но поробую еще раз после прочтения ресурса.

Comment: вероятно ты ищешь функцию initSplash в js/script.js на 374 строке

Comment: либо метод _prevPageAnimate_ в js/script.js на 194 строке

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Grundy, да я уже понял, что initSplash рисует менюшку.

Comment: Может есть кто-то кто научился дебажить по книге или видеокурсам какого-то блоггера?